# unable to POST request with sprint WebClient : always 400

Tags: java, rest, post, spring-webclient

very big problem since 48h00.
with postman, absolutly no problem to post my body. return is 200.
there is no authentication with concerned api.
but, when i use my java-code, always 400 is returned !!!!

```
  String baseUrl = "myBaseUrl";
  String uri = "myUri";
  WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);
  ClientResponse cresponse = webClient
  .post()
  .uri(uri)
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
  .syncBody(myObject)
  .exchange()
  .block();

  // always 400!!!! here !!!!!!!
  System.out.println("result :" + cresponse.statusCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something wrong with "myObject".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way in you are feeding the body in your request. Use Mono.just to create a mono to feed the body as shown below

webClient.post().body(Mono.just(myObject)), MyObject.class).exchange().block().statusCode();